# How to download images from the Digital Ocean Spaces using AWS SDK for Android?

Tags: java, android, digital-ocean

Since Digital Ocean Spaces API is compatible with AWS SDK, how to download images from Digital Ocean Spaces programmatically using AWS SDK for Android?